# Follow-up comparisons from LMEM interaction

Tags: mixed-model, binomial-distribution, interaction, post-hoc

I have a dataset that consists of three predictor variables: time (1,2,3; within-subjects), density (1,2; within-subjects), vocabulary ability (continuous; between-subjects). The dependent variable is accuracy (0, 1), and I want to incorporate by-participant (ID) and by-item random effects in my analysis.

I centred my predictors (.c to each variable name), and ran a maximally specified mixed effects model as follows:

```
max.model <- glmer(acc ~ time.c*density.c*vocab.c + (1+time.c*density.c|ID) + (1+time.c*vocab.c|item), data = CR.trim3, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"))
```

So far so good (as far as I am aware - the output makes sense at least). I now want to follow up the significant time*density interaction, using pairwise comparisons between density conditions at each time point separately. I've heard that simply running the model on partial datasets is wrong, and understand that packages like phia and lsMeans are the solution. However, I've wasted lots of time trying to figure out how these work and still keep getting errors.

For example, if I enter:

```
testInteractions(max.model, pairwise = c("time.c", "density.c"), adjustment = "bonferroni")
```

I get:

```
Chisq Test: 
P-value adjustment method: bonferroni
       Value Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)   
Mean 0.30091  1 9.7896   0.001755 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Warning message:
In testInteractions(max.model, pairwise = c("time.c", "density.c"),  :
  Some factors with specified contrasts are not in the model and will be ignored.
```

Other attempts have also produced errors regarding "intra-subjects" but maybe I have resolved this now. Where have I gone wrong? Have I done something wrong in specifying my model in the first place?

Many thanks,
Emma

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your max.model treats time as a continuous variable, so there's nothing to follow up.

Rather than trying to center factors with more than 2 levels, you might prefer the Anova (capitalization important) function from the car package.

Comment: Thanks James! So time needs to be specified as a factor? I'd tried something along those lines before but lme didn't seem to like it, and I wasn't sure enough with what I was doing. I've been reading around a bit - do I need to do more in terms of dummy coding? 

Interested by Anova option though - so does this essentially compute test statistics for the model? So I could run the model on non-centred predictors, and then use Anova on the model to compute p-values? Then still use phia etc. to follow up interactions? 

Sorry for all the questions, very much on a steep LMEM learning curve!

Comment: Yes, Anova computes tests for the model, rather than you interpreting model coefficients directly. This means using factors as normal, and only centering your continuous variable. This should make phia happier.

Comment: Binomial models can have problems if a participant is at ceiling or floor in a particular cell of the design, or if there's a participant-cell with too few data. Using continuous time may have inadvertently prevented one of these issues.